# как избавиться от nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, исключения

Изучаю java не долго. Первий раз сталкиваюсь с nullPointerException.

Задания:
вывести длину строку. Если значения строки равно "" или null вывести 0.

Вот код

```
 public static int stringLength(String input) {
  
  return input.length() > 0  ?  input.length() : 0;
}
```

И ошибка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GetStringLength.stringLength(GetStringLength.java:4)
    at GetStringLengthTest.stringLength_null(GetStringLengthTest.java:44)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у null объекта нельзя вызвать метод length(), из-за этого и падает исключение nullPointerExeption.

```
return input!=null  ?  input.length() : 0;
```